# add_action in the loop hooks

Tags: loop, hooks, actions

I have the following structure:

```
add_action('my_content', 'standard_loop');
function standard_loop() {
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
         do_action('loop_entry_before');
         do_action('loop_entry');
         do_action('loop_entry_after');
   endwhile;
endif;
}
add_action('loop_entry_before', 'do_entry', 1);
function do_entry() {
   if ( get_the_title() ) {
      add_action('loop_entry_before', 'function_that_adds_h2_structure');
   }
   add_action('loop_entry_entry', 'function_that_adds_content_structure');
}
```

The issue is that all post display the function_that_adds_h2_structure even if is only empty html and the post has no title.
This is just an example for using login in the do_entry();

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a fucntion has been hooked to an action, the function will be executed every time the action is called (with `do_action`). To stop this, the action should be removed. See [`remove_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action):

```
function do_entry() {
   if ( get_the_title() ) {
      add_action('loop_entry_before', 'function_that_adds_h2_structure');
   } else {
      remove_action('loop_entry_before', 'function_that_adds_h2_structure');
   }
   add_action('loop_entry_entry', 'function_that_adds_content_structure');
}
```

In your case, I think that the actions hook approach is not very good and it can be better to do direct function calls:

```
function do_entry() {
   if ( get_the_title() ) {
      function_that_adds_h2_structure();
   }
   add_action('loop_entry_entry', 'function_that_adds_content_structure');
}
```